# How do I initialize these arrays?

Tags: kotlin

I want to have a class that stores three sets of 30 Foos each. I can declare them as arrays of Foo but I don't know how I can initialize them (give them default values) with 30 elements.

```
data class Container (
    val first: Array<Foo>,
    val second: Array<Foo>,
    val third: Array<Foo>,
)

data class Foo (val a: Int, val b: Int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't too many ways to create an array in Kotlin and they are pretty straightforward. Depending on your needs, you can either use [arrayOf() function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html), [Array() constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) or create `List` first and then convert it into array.

Example with `arrayOf()`:

```kotlin
val first = arrayOf(
    Foo(0, 0),
    Foo(1, 1),
    ...
)
```

`Array()`:

```kotlin
val first = Array(30) { Foo(it, it) }
```

List:

```kotlin
val firstList = mutableListOf<Foo>()
firstList += Foo(0, 0)
firstList += Foo(1, 1)
...
first = firstList.toTypedArray()
```

If the code for generating these arrays is complicated, you can write it inside `init {}` block or create static function(s) that provides these arrays.

Comment: I tried the second way and I got an error. Turned out it was only an error because I had written `val first: Array<Foo>= Array(30) { Foo(it, it) },` with no space between `>` and `=`.